# Nmap Ping Scanning

Tags: ruby, networking, nmap

I'm using Ruby to run an `nmap -sP` ping scan on my home network continuously to check for new hosts connecting. A couple of questions:

- Is there a better way to do this?
- How effective is `-sP` at finding new hosts?
- Will running this over and over on a loop create any problems for my home network which is used just for casual web browsing?

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Using Ruby. Should I just delete this thread or keep it and have two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

This is good enough if hosts are guaranteed to accept pings; however, sometimes `nmap -sP` can spew packets faster than wifi networks can deal with them.  If you see issues like this, just lower the rate with `nmap --scan-delay 0.1 -sP`.

> How effective is -sP at finding new hosts?

As good as ping is; however, fresh Windows installations often block ping by default.  You could run `nmap -sT -P0` just to be sure you got everything...

The ultimate host detection scheme is to poll your ethernet switch for new mac-address entries.

> Will running this over and over on a loop create any problems for my home network which is used just for casual web browsing?

Nope

Comment: Fantastic! Any advice on where to look for learning how to poll for mac addresses? Search terms?

Comment: If this is an enterprise device, you could use `snmp` and poll `dot1qTpFdbTable` from the [`Q-Bridge-MIB`](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/Q-BRIDGE-MIB.html).  For consumer ethernet switches, you usually can't get it with `snmp`... use their web GUI if they provide that much information

Comment: Nmap host detection (`-sn`, formerly `-sP`) does more than just an ICMP echo request (a la ping). Assuming you are running as root, it also tries a TCP SYN to port 80, TCP ACK to port 443, and an ICMP Timestamp request. `nmap -sT -P0` will take ages, don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to use your switch ("router") to check for new clients on the network. Most home wireless routers will have a Web page listing the current DHCP leases, which you could poll from your Ruby script. There may also be a page listing all MAC addresses associated with the network (essentially the switch's ARP table).

Comment: I like this idea. Such a page exists in my case featuring complete information. I didn't really know how to approach the problem, but Google turned up Watir and it seems to do the job very well considering that I am a total beginner. I noticed that the client list showing up on the router doesn't seem to be updated since there are clients on there after they have been removed from the network. Is that normal? Also - for cases where `-sn` isn't working and I have the MAC address, where's the best unobtrusive type of scan to do to make sure the host is present on the network?

Comment: That is normal. The router doesn't have any way to know if the host has left or is ever coming back. Cached entries probably expire after a set amount of time. If -sn doesn't work, then nothing will (on the same segment), since if you can't complete an ARP request, then you can't talk to the host at all. You could assume it's down/gone. Another tool to do a similar thing is arping, or you could try a Ruby [packet-crafting library](http://www.tmplab.org/2010/10/03/packet-crafting-toolkits-in-ruby/)

Comment: Alright, thanks so much! I can't seem to find `-sn` in the man page - is it only to be found in nmap 6? The listing for `-sP-` seems to match what you described above, so I'm guessing that it changed over from ver. 5 to 6.

Comment: The -sn syntax was added in 5.30BETA1. -sP is indeed the old (and still valid) way to specify it.